# Django error: Command throws a python window when executing makemigrations command in a Python/Django project

Tags: django, python-2.7

python ´2.7.13´

Django ´1.9.7´

i'm using ´viertualenv´ to manage my project.

i tried to run this command and this happends

```
(pyproject-1)xxxxx@xxxx.com
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and it open a new window with the pyshell

```
python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500
32 bit<intel> on win 32]
type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Using de ´migrate´ or ´runserver´ command still opens the windows

what could be the error? i googled this and i don't find clear answers

Comment: How did you create your django project

Comment: - installed python
- instaled Django on the folder if the proyect
- instaled setuptools
- created the virtualenv
- startproject

step by step to instalation and creation of the project

Comment: try to `chmod +x manage.py` and run it as `./manage.py makemigrations` if that will behave the same

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko thank you very much! it worked! y use

`manage.py makemigrations` and
`./manage.py makemigrations`

without the word **python** and works, it rare, in other computers works with the python word

Answer (score 0):

*[update]*

the error in my project was a virus that reanamed all the files with a "G" including executed files: "Gpython.exe" "GManage.py" making the troubleshooting en my proyect, perhaps, the command `.\manage.py makemigrations` or `.\manage.py migrate` still worked with the virus.

PD:Sorry, i'm still learning english languaje :P