# Conda keep opening this Python Interpreter

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda 3. After Install I reboot the computer but, when I opened Anaconda Navigator, this keep happening, first this CMD window appears [Conda.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrOBL.jpg)

and then this window appears [gpython.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKwXA.jpg)

Before reboot, everything fine, I could open Anaconda Navigator. After reboot, (insert Billy Butcher from the Boys) BOOM, this happen.

This also happens everytime I type "conda" on the command prompt,with the python interpreter (second picture) keep  appearing. So pretty much any solution on the internet that told me to use "conda" doesnt help.

Also this happens to every Anaconda Application (Anaconda Prompt, Anaconda Navigator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that whenever you launch anaconda conda.exe will run, at least it does for me.

Regarding gpython.exe, I could only find the following question referring to it
[Django error: Command throws a python window when executing makemigrations command in a Python/Django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075918/django-error-command-throws-a-python-window-when-executing-makemigrations-comma/42231494#42231494)

This makes it seem like your anaconda may require a reinstall, I checked my anaconda files and couldn't find a gpython.exe in the path where yours appears, so this may be the case. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the response. I actually just installed the anaconda tho, but I already uninstalled and will i install it again.

Comment: So before installing anaconda, should I remove the python that is already installed on my computer?

Comment: I don't think that will be necessary, I didn't need to, keep me posted and i may be able to help

Comment: in the advanced options, which one should i check? the add path or register anaconda as default python? or both?

Comment: If you only plan on using anaconda for python, make it default python

Comment: WOW IT WORKED. After reinstall everything went find. I reboot several times and it still work. After this is done, should i add conda in my environment variables?

Comment: I don't remember having to do that, so you shouldn't need to i don't think